# Image is not loading with picasso in android api 19 and below

Tags: android, picasso, lib

On the left is the list displayed in API level 19 and on the right is API 28. For API 19 I am unable to load flag Images using Picasso. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU7QJ.png

This is how I am doing it right now.

```
interface ImageFetcher {
    fun loadImage(url: String, callback: (bitmap: Bitmap) -> Unit)
}

class RemoteImageFetcher(val context: Context) : ImageFetcher {
    override fun loadImage(url: String, callback: (bitmap: Bitmap) -> Unit) {
        val target = object : com.squareup.picasso.Target {
            override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
                callback.invoke(bitmap)
            }
            override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {}
            override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {}
        }
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(target)
        
    }
```

Comment: try adding ``.setLoggingEnabled(true)``after your Picasso ``get()`` call (so ``Picasso.get().setLoggingEnabled(true).load(url).into(target)``) and see what error messages you get in the logs

Comment: Thank you. After adding the section in my code. the log produced is  Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.getPlaceholderDrawable

Comment: Weird, the ``RequestCreator`` class only calls that method on API 21+, it uses ``ContextCompat`` which should call ``context.getResources().getDrawable()`` instead. I don't know what would help, but if you're using a vector drawable placeholder somewhere, try a bitmap one instead, just in case it's related to that somehow. And maybe try setting a breakpoint and stepping through with the debugger, see if you can find out why it's making that ``context.getDrawable()`` call